# When creating a variable from command output, Bash removes a backslash from the JSON. How do I make it keep both backslashes to maintain valid JSON?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm doing the following to capture some ADO JSON data:

```
iteration="$(az boards iteration team list --team Test --project Test --timeframe current)"
```

Normally, the output of that command contains a JSON key/value pair like the following:

```
"path": "Test\\Sprint1"
```

But after capturing the STDOUT into that iteration variable, if I do

```
echo "$iteration"
```

That key/value pair becomes

```
"path": "Test\Sprint1"
```

And if I attempt to use jq on that output, it breaks because it's not recognized as valid JSON any longer. I'm very unfamiliar with Bash. How can I get that JSON to remain valid all the way through?

Comment: depending on your version of `echo` (builtin? binary? alias/function?) you could try explicitly suppressing the interpretation of the backslashes: `echo -E "$iteration"`; note: in my system `echo "$iteration"` generates the desired output while `echo -e "$iteration"` generates the 'bad' output, while `echo -E "$iteration"` also generates the desired output

Comment: @markp-fuso Some versions of `echo` will simply print the "-E" as part of their output, making the whole situation even worse. It can depend on which shell it's run under, what environment variables are set, what OS and version it's run on, etc etc etc. It's much safer to use `printf` with a proper format string. See ["Why is printf better than echo?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) on the Unix&Linux stackexchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already [commented by markp-fuso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75415079/when-creating-a-variable-from-command-output-bash-removes-a-backslash-from-the#comment133067574_75415079):

It looks like your `echo` command is interpreting the backslashes. You can confirm this by running `echo 'a\\b'` and looking at the output.

The portable way to deal with such problems is to use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
printf %s\\n "$iteration"
```